# Azure file share for SQL Server backups

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, file, backup

I have a standalone MS SQL Server and azure File share mounted on the same windows server, however when I try to configure backup maintenance plan I do not see the Azure file share which is mapped to Z. Chanting the permissions of SQL Server and SQL Server agent user context to the local user does not help. How can I use mounted Azure file share for SQL Server direct backups?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get backup for SQL VMs (among other things) is to register your VM hosted VM with the SQL Server VM resource provider.  Once you do, you can manage backups from the Azure portal and configure storage accounts directly using blobs instead of mounted file shares which I believe mount based on the context in which you mounted them.  After following the steps, you should get SQL management blades in the Azure portal for your VM as if you created the VM based on an existing SQL image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-vm-resource-provider-register?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash

## Register the SQL VM resource provider to your subscription

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine
```

## Get the existing  Compute VM

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name <vm_name> -ResourceGroupName <resource_group_name>
```

## Register with SQL VM resource provider in full mode

```
New-AzSqlVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -SqlManagementType Full
```